# Trying to create a times table program for a range of tables

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to create a program that will display times tables for a user, the times tables displayed should be between two user inputted numbers. for example, the user inputs 4 and 8, the program should display the 4 times table, the 5 times table, the 6 times table, the 7 times table and the 8 times table. I am very new to Java, I have looked online, but I couldn't really find anything that helped me a great deal. I am slowly understanding loops, but as I mentioned before, I am very much still a novice. Thank you :)!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class timesTables
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        // variables
        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 0;

        // open scanner
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // ask user for a table number
        System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");

        // store input in a variable
        num1 = sc.nextInt();

        // ask user for another table number
        System.out.println("Please enter another number: ");

        // store input in a variable
        num2 = sc.nextInt();

        // display times table from num1 to num2
        /* for (int i = 0; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            // multiply num1 by i
            int j = num1 * i;

            // display result of previous calculation
            System.out.println(j);
        } */

        for (int n = 1; num1 == num2; num1++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 12; j++)
            {
                // multiply num1 by j
                int multiplication = num1 * j;

                // display result of previous calculation
                System.out.println(multiplication);
            }
        }

        // close scanner
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (int j = 1; j <= 12; j++)` means “run the body of this loop as long as j is less than or equal to 12.”  `for (int n = 1; num1 == num2; num1++)` means “run the body this loop as long as num1 is exactly equal to num2.”  If num1 and num2 are not equal to begin with, the loop will run zero times.  Perhaps you meant to write `num1 <= num2`?

Comment: What is the expected output? What do the terms **the 4 times table, the 5 times table ...** mean? Can you add your desired output for your example values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the following condition in the external loop:

```
num1 == num2
```

In order to make `for` cycle work, it should become `true`. In your case you should replace `num1 == num2` with `num1 <= num2`:

```
for (int n = 1; num1 <= num2; num1++)
```

Comment: Thank you, just tried it out, worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Loop from *num1* to *num2* inclusive, and then from *1* to *12*.

```java
for (int i = num1, j; i <= num2; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= 12; j++)
        System.out.printf("%s x %s = %s%n", i, j, i * j);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Here is an example output.

```
5 x 1 = 5
5 x 2 = 10
5 x 3 = 15
5 x 4 = 20
5 x 5 = 25
5 x 6 = 30
5 x 7 = 35
5 x 8 = 40
5 x 9 = 45
5 x 10 = 50
5 x 11 = 55
5 x 12 = 60
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this, I managed to solve the problem!